# How to save datetime from MySQL into SESSION in php?

Tags: php, mysql, session

How can I save 'date_time' which is a datetime type into a session so I can display ex. "Registered 2013-04-09 15:45:20" on the page secret_place.php

I have this code in login.php

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `user`, `pass`, `date_time` FROM `database` WHERE user = '".$user."' AND pass = '".$pass."' LIMIT 1");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
$_SESSION['logged'] = true;
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;

header('Location: secret_place.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try,

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `user`, `pass`, `date_time` FROM `database` WHERE user = '".$user."' AND pass = '".$pass."' LIMIT 1");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) 
{
   $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
   $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
   {
       $_SESSION['date_time'] = $row['date_time'];
   }
   header('Location: secret_place.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some serious issues, here:
First of all, [**please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). That way you'll also prevent **SQL injection attacks**, right now your code is wide open to them.

Also **do not store plain password** in the DB. Store it hashed, using some proper lib, like [PasswordLib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-PasswordLib)

Comment: This might be a very good suggestion, but is it really an answer to the question? Doesn't mention anything related to question

Comment: I use: mysql_real_escape_string and htmlentities in my code.
The password is salted and I don't use md5 for password.
I will look into PDO and MySQLi nevertheless.
Thank you.